# mysql prevent duplicate insert of more than one foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

The first is called 'users' and has 3 columns. id (PK), name and email.

The second is called 'courses' and also has 3 columns: id (PK), name and code.

The third is called 'user_courses' and is used to join the users and courses tables. It to has 3 columns: id (PK), userFK (fk to users.id) and courseFK (fk to courses.id)

A user can only apply for a course once, however i can insert user with value '1' and course  with value '1' multiple times.

My question is how do i prevent having a duplicate userFK, courseFK combination in the user_courses table?

Comment: Why not remove "id" and use the duet "userFK" + "courseFK" as your primary key in your user_courses table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a composite unique key on (userFK,courseFK):

```
ALTER TABLE `user_courses` ADD UNIQUE (`userFK`,`courseFK`);
```